# PHP mail() - How to set Priority?

Tags: php, email

Is there any way to set the priority of PHP mail()? I looked at the online manual but I can't find any reference to it.

By priority, I mean High, Normal, Low or 1, 2, 3 in the headers. So the recipient knows the urgency of the mail.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean in terms of how outbound mail is queued? Or are you asking about the various `Priority:` headers that cause some mail clients to render messages with red exclamation marks and such?

Comment: Except some people didn't spellcheck.

Comment: @Everyone : how about gmail that dun have priority feature? or any alternative for gmail?

Comment: @ajreal: Anyway, priority, as the accused resseption, are so unreliable functionalities...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

That's usually done by setting following fields in the header:

- "X-Priority" (values: 1 to 5- from the highest[1] to lowest[5]),
- "X-MSMail-Priority" (values: High, Normal, or Low),
- "Importance" (values: High, Normal, or Low).

See the following example (taken from php's mail function documentation):

```
<?php
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n";
        $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
        $headers .= "Importance: High\n";

 $status   = mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Why not one multiline string instead?

Comment: Shoudn't it be "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)".PHP_EOL ?

Comment: Are there any specs that define these headers? And any documentation in gmail/outlook/thunderbird/whatever that shows which header is considered? [Edit]: I've found this one https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml that points to RFC4021 but it states header is `Priority` and not `X-Priority`

Comment: @PavelLebedeff The [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#91058) say: If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html). But honestly, I think it's time to get with the times. `\n` is the best way to do new lines, and we shouldn't need two chars for `\r\n`.

Comment: As @Xenos points out, the standards are a bit spotty.  As of 2012, `X-` prefixing has been deprecated (["it wasn't a good idea, it leads to problems, we're sorry"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648)) however the situation of needing to specify all variants will persist as long as the mail clients that use those forms do. Interestingly, there's a warning on RFC4021 marking `Priority` as "not for general use".  [RFC 2156](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2156/?include_text=1) as quite a bit more to say about this header, within the context of mapping X.400 to MIME.

Comment: @Xenos `Priority` and `X-Priority` are two entirely different things. While `X-Priority` is a vendor-specific non-standard extension (hence the "X-"), `Priority` is meant to tell MTAs to prioritize the mail during transfer, which I guess will be ignored most of the time. `Importance` is the only standard header to mark a mail as high priority for the user.

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php 
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"; 
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n"; 
        $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n"; 
        $headers .= "Importance: High\n"; 

        $status = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
?>
```

From: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#91058

Answer (score 2):

Call it with the X-Priority header in the 4th parameter:

```
mail ( $to, $subject, $message , "X-Priority: 1")
```

Comment: Down-voted: no reference to the original RFC which states 1 is the lowest priority level: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc577. *At least* the other posts add `High` or `Highest`. In programming subjectivity is wastes massive amounts of time.

Comment: Good point. And what's with the shitty formatting, I guess I copied that from somewhere? Note that Outlook uses `X-priority: 2`, so in practice I wouldn't actually add anything to that. I'd keep it in a constant of course.

Answer (score 1):

[A comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#91058) on the [PHP mail function documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) said:

```
<?php 
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ; 
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"; 
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n"; 
        $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n"; 
        $headers .= "Importance: High\n"; 

        $status   = mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a mail priority you have to put this lines in the headers:

```
<?php 
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ; 
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"; 
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n"; 
        $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n"; 
        $headers .= "Importance: High\n"; 

 $status   = mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers); 
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: why are there three different headers for priority? Also, what is Higuest? Is that a misspelling? I actually saw this one but didn't feel like it was on solid grounds.

Comment: yea .mis spell .. by the guy who wrote that. I got it from php.net :)

Comment: @Scott W.: Different mail programs use different priority headers. I love standards.

Answer (score -1):

everything didn't work except this for my problem

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: xyz@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: Admin@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

PS: email body must before the headers.