# Php mail() - Priority types

Tags: php

want to know what are the php mail() priority types. I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169605/php-mail-how-to-set-priority) and I read the php manual,

```
<?php
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Higuest)\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
    $headers .= "Importance: High\n";
    $status   = mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
?>
```

but its not explain what are the types we can used. `X-Priority: 1 (Higuest)` and `X-MSMail-Priority: High` two different words used for this. there are few types of priority I found. ex: Low, Medium, High, Urgent, Emergency, Critical how we used this types.

Comment: There is no standard for these. Every mail app makes these up on their own. Consult the documentation of the mail client you're targeting, if available.

Comment: Presumably, that should read "Highest" - not "Higuest" ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Values: 1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = Low

you need not enter both lines, use either X-MSMail-Priority or X-Priority

> Alternative to X-Priority, although X-Priority is preferred. "High"
>   corresponds to X-Priority: 1, "Normal" is the same as X-Priority: 3,
>   and "Low" is the same as "X-Priority: 5". Including both X-Priority
>   and X-MSMailPriority in the same email header is OK, although it
>   probably best they agree.
>
> Example:
>
> either
>
> X-MSMail-Priority: High
>
> or
>
> X-Priority: 1

and go through this link, you'll get to know about mail function more

http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/avoid-spam-filters-with-php-mail-emails/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the equivalents. MailMate offers X-Priority but with no explanation. Looking to replicate Apple Mail High Priority. Got it now. Anyone else looking for MailMate info, here's the command to get X-Priority headers: `defaults write com.freron.MailMate MmAdditionalComposerHeaders "( { headerName = 'X-Priority'; defaultValue = '3'; type = 'plain'; } )"` with default of normal.