# golang smtp making the mail as hipri or important

Tags: email, go

I tried to send a email using golang smtp https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SendingMail and able to send email properly. Below is the code snippet

```
func sendEmail(server string) {
// Connect to the server, set the sender and recipient,
// and send the email all in one step.
headers := make(map[string]string)

headers["Subject"] = "Hi-Pri# Server " + server + " down"
headers["From"] = "YYYY@net"
headers["To"] = "XXXX@net"

body := "Hello, Test"

// Setup message
message := ""
for k, v := range headers {
    message += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s\r\n", k, v)
}
message += "\r\n" + body
err := smtp.SendMail(
    "test.com:25",
    nil,
    "YYYY@net",
    []string{"XXXX@net"},
    []byte(message),
)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Im trying to send a hipri mail but couldn't fine the option to make a mail as hirpri or important one. Can someone help me

Comment: Email priority isn't part of SMTP, or even a standard. Your email client probably uses an `X-Priority` header to communicate importance.

Comment: so you are telling that there is no way to make the mail as hi-rpi

Comment: No, I'm saying set whatever header your email client uses, to the value it interprets as "high priority".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail() - How to set Priority?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169605/php-mail-how-to-set-priority) -- while the question is nominally for PHP, the answer is basically language-independent.

Comment: I fixed it as suggested by JimB and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Add to your code:

```
headers["X-Priority"] = "1 (Highest)"
headers["X-MSMail-Priority"] = "High"
headers["Importance"] = "High"
```

That should work. 
However as said in comments, priority will be interpreted by your client, not your server. Will 100% depends on what your mail client decides to show.